# How to host multiple virtual host webservers with different ssl certificates in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, express, http, https, tcp

I understand how to create a simple virtual host webserver in node js, but not how to create a virtual host webserver that uses https protocols. I want to host 3 different sites with 3 different certificates but I am unsure how to do that. I've tried using things diet js but it doesn't work for me because it's too old and hasn't been updated. I can't use three different servers because I only have one IP to serve on and I have to only use one port. How should I go about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use NGINX as reverse proxy configured for that. Node.js is not a webserver. You can write a webserver in node, but there a better allready existing solutions.

Comment: Thanks, Marc, but I don't want to use a proxy at all. Just my personal preference. Don't worry I know node js isn't a web server, I've used it for quite a while. I just need to know how to make a virtual host with separate SSL certificates. Although I think I have found the solution to my problem after looking at the diet js source code on github.